# IOS Objective-C How to assign 2 viewControllers to the same UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

sorry for my English. I try to exlpain my problem.
I have a Storyboard with a UITabBarController with 5 UITabBarItems and 5 viewControllers associated.
My problem is that one of these tab items should not automatically open the viewController associated: on click, I should perform an asynchronous request to a web service and, based on the response, I should set one viewController or another as his rootViewController. Is it possible? How?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly make this call in UITabBarController's delegate

*tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:*
**OR**
*tabBarController:didSelectViewController:*

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3ashouldSelectViewController):

But the better approach would be to create a viewcontroller thats only job is to fire off that request and then push on the nav stack whichever controller you desire.

Also evaluate the need for having two separate controllers.

Comment: I tried to create a viewcontroller (say V1) and use that only to make the choice; anyway, once I choose the correct viewcontroller  (say V2) and push it, V1 remains the root of the navigation stack, while I’d need V2 to be the root of the navigation stack. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Push it then, from v2, [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:V2ViewController] animated:YES];